# Add dynamically onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

Good morning in my timezone.

I have the following html structure in a page:

```
...
 <span id="x">
   <div>
     Text
   </div>
 </span>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#x div").click(function(){"alert('Teste');"});

});

</scrip>
```

I want to add an onclick event dynamically to the div under the span ,
but nothing is happen.No errors on console in chrome.
What is missing ?I am new to jquery

Best regards
Thanks in advance

Comment: It has to be `$("#x div").click(function() { alert('Teste'); });`.

Comment: Everything is fine, but you have placed the function inside double quotes `"alert('Teste');"`

Comment: It's not valid to have block elements inside inline elements!

Comment: @Justinas indeed it is. But at least without `""` and with `#x` code works.

Comment: @Regent If it's working, it does not mean that you have good quality code.

Comment: i was using the $("#x div") , i put it wrong in the question

Comment: Surely you mean console.log('Taste'); rather then alert??

Comment: $("#x div").click(function(){"alert('Teste');"});
Nothing happens with this code

Comment: @Justinas I have already tired trying to force people in SO to make  things in good, proper way. So we are stuck with "at least it works".

Comment: @Regent `force people in SO...` Are you talking about slavery?

Comment: @tt0686 what for do you add `""` in click? Remove them. Are you familiar with JS at all?

Comment: In addition to the same thing everybody feels the need to repeat and repeat, also check your closing script tag (you're missing a `t`)

Comment: @Regent - he obviously is at least a bit familiar, why are you asking that? Are you being sarcastic for some reason?

Comment: the script is right , that is just a code snippet

Comment: It's an inaccurate code snippet then.

Comment: @Justinas nope, just not the best verb in phrase. Something like "convince" would be more appropriate.

Comment: @DeeMac because I don't know how you can write `$("#x div").click("function() { alert('Teste'); }");` and wonder why this code causes an error.

Comment: Well I'll give you one reason, because somebody is not as experienced in javascript as what that problem would require. Still doesn't warrant your sarcasm. There's no need to put people down. When you started out - did you not make silly mistakes yourself? Don't be patronising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does nothing. Remove `"` from around `alert()`.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#x div").click(function() {
     alert('Teste');
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="x">
  <div>
    Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks , you were a great help

Answer (score 0):

To attach events to dynamic DOM elements use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). In your scenario

```
$(document).on('click', '#x div:first', function(e){
   alert('test');
});
```